# Run periodic codes to mongoDB in Azure VM

Tags: mongodb, azure, virtual-machine

I have the following :

1. Azure VM (Windows).
2. Installed MongoDB in the VM.

My plan :

1. Write python script to **run periodically** (say every 5 minutes) to pump the data into MongoDB.
2. Initial plan is to use *WebJob* to run the script periodically then I realised I am not sure how to access MongoDB VM through Azure portal

My question :

1. Is it possible to connect MongoDB VM through Azure portal? How?
2. What other services may be more suitable in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to connect MongoDB VM through the Azure portal? How?

The Azure portal can only help you control the VM and the related resources, such as network, disk and etc. But it cannot help you to connect to the application inside the VM. What you can do is like the things you normally do. Give the interface to access outside the VM. Treat the VM as a DB server like physically do. In addition, you need to open the port is the NSG if you create it and associate it with the VM nic or subnet.

> What other services may be more suitable in this case?

Maybe you can use the [MongoDB Atlas on Azure](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas/azure-mongodb) and the WebJob. But I think that install the MongoDB in the VM is also suitable. You can follow the steps in [Integrate your app with an Azure Virtual Network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet) to combine your WebJob with the Vnet which you VM in so that your WebJob can connect with the MongoDB in the VM a private network.

Comment: Thanks! I am aware of MongoDB Atlas but I am also aware of the price. So I installed MongoDB in VM and intending to establish connection from the VM to Webjob. From your answer, public IP address is not necessary to establish the connection then. I'm going to take a look at VNet. To be completely honest I don't understand VNet much.

Comment: @cna The Vnet looks like a private network as local. It's not special things you never see. Well, if you don't mind you can accept the answer. Or more help is also free.

Comment: I would like to get your opinion though. My pipeline is a real time streaming processing which is why I intended to use WebJob in the first place. But I figured another way of doing this.. I used Jenkins to run the pipeline instead (seems reliable so far). Do you think this is a good practice for building real-time pipeline? I think less set up is required and it is cheaper than using WebJob..

Comment: @cna Yeah, maybe use the Jenkins is more suitable for the real-time work.